# Sound can't finish when form submited in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to add a sound when the submit button in my form is pressed, but no matter what I do, the sound doesn't finish. It is 1 second long, but the form is submitted under 1 second, so it sounds really bad. This is the code:

Creating the sound:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var html5_audiotypes={ 
        "mp3": "audio/mpeg"
    }

    function createsoundbite(sound){
        var html5audio=document.createElement('audio')
        if (html5audio.canPlayType){
            for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
                var sourceel=document.createElement('source')
                sourceel.setAttribute('src', arguments[i])
                if (arguments[i].match(/\.(\w+)$/i))
                    sourceel.setAttribute('type', html5_audiotypes[RegExp.$1])
                html5audio.appendChild(sourceel)
            }
            html5audio.load()
            html5audio.playclip=function(){
                html5audio.pause()
                html5audio.currentTime=0
                html5audio.play()
            }
            return html5audio
        }
        else{
            return {playclip:function(){throw new Error("Your browser doesn't support HTML5 audio unfortunately")}}
        }
    }
    var mouseClick=createsoundbite("sounds/cashSound.mp3")
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form method='post' action='save.php'>
    <input type='submit' name='apply' value='Play' onclick='mouseClick.playclip()' />
</form>
```

I tried the setTimeout function but it didn't work! Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion: Please don't play random sounds on your website? :) Please‽

Comment: Sounds effects in websites are totally bad and avoidable.

Comment: I guarantee I will not be using your website if this actually happens.

Comment: Big + 1. Please do not add some sound on your website ... :/

Comment: yeah...it's pretty annoying to be on facebook now, since they installed sounds for notifications :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to return false in playClip function. This may cause, the submit action will not be performed. You can wait for one second and call submit() on form element. You can also send form by AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the aesthetics, if you really want the sound to finish, then you'll need to delay submission / delay the response or play the sound in a seperate frame, one which is not embedded within the same page as the form.

Comment: ew, you don't need a frame; just submit through ajax.

Comment: presumably the 'submit' is supposed to do something more than just play a sound - fetching the response and rendering  via javascript has all sorts of complications which I don't think the OP will appreciate.